# Assign a Value to a HTML Table Cell using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

There is a table displaying model entries, with each field designated a unique div id combining a keyword and each row's ID.  When the user enters a number in the table's input column, a script is supposed to: get the locations of the cells on the same row; and change the values of two predetermined cells based on the values of the other cells.
It seems that tests are successful until the final updating.  I've tried using .val(), .value, and .html(), and the resultant cells go blank, or show 0 if the script is error-free.  Would someone please post the correct jQuery command and why it works?  Many thanks in advance.

The table:

```
<table id="dt_Positions" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Month</th>
            <th class="text-center">Owed</th>
            <th class="text-center">Bought</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total Position</th>
            <th class="text-center">Non-Fixed</th>
            <th class="text-center">Fixed</th>
            <th class="text-center">Fixed Position</th>
            <th class="text-center">Proposed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Forecasts.Any())
        {
            foreach (var record in Model.Summaries)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td id="nmonth@(record.fID)" align="center">@String.Format("{0:d}", @record.Month)</td>
                    <td id="ntotal@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NTotal</td>
                    <td id="nbought@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NBought</td>
                    <td id="ntposition@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NTotalPosition</td>
                    <td id="nvariable@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NVariable</td>
                    <td id="nfixed@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NFixed</td>
                    <td id="nfposition@(record.fID)" align="center">@record.NFPosition</td>
                    <td id="ninput@(record.fID)" align="center"><input class="nInput" type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="50000"></td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The script:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id^=ninput]').keyup(function (e) {
                var $id = $(this).attr('id');
                var $i = $(this);
                var $idNum = $id.slice(6);
                var $tp = $('#ntposition' + $idNum);
                var $fp = $('#nfposition' + $idNum);
                var $nt = $('#ntotal' + $idNum);
                var $nh = $('#nbought' + $idNum);
                var $f = $('#nfixed' + $idNum);
                //The lines below appear to be the hiccup
                $tp.val($nh.val() + $i.html() - $nt.val());
                $fp.val($nh.val() + $i.html() - $f.val());
                debugger;
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**EDIT:**  Examples of ids returning "NaN" are:
ntotal = 29, nbought = 5, ntposition = -24, nvariable = 3, nfixed = 26, nfposition = -21, with all appearing to be int from testing the View, but ntotal, nbought, and nfixed showing "NaN" in the console.log and resulting in "NaN" appearing in the test View after an ninput = 5.

Comment: There is no need to use `id` attributes here (and doing so is just over complicating you code). Use relative selectors - `$('input').keyup(function() { var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td'); ` Then you can access the values of the cells using `var nh = cells.eq(2).text();` etc. (note its `text()` not `val()`)

Comment: Thank you Stephen Muecke.  I'm new to relative selectors in jQuery, so I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$i` is the textbox, so to get its value you need to use `$i.val()`. The other elements are table cells, so to get or set the values you need `.text()`, not `.val()`. However you over complicating code by using `id` attributes. Instead, remove then and use relative selectors

```
$('input').keyup(function() { // or $('.nInput').keyup
  var i = Number$(this).val());
  var cells = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');

  var tp = cells.eq(3);
  var fp = cells.eq(6);
  // Get current cell values as a number
  var nt = Number(cells.eq(1).text());
  var nh = Number(cells.eq(2).text());
  var f = Number(cells.eq(5).text());
  // Update totals
  tp.text(nh + i - nt);
  fp.text(nh + i - f);

});
```

Side note: The value of `var i = $(this).val();` could be `null` but not sure how you want to handle this - possibly just use

```
var i = $(this).val();
if (!i) {
  return; // don't do any calculations
}
```

Comment: I prefer this to my lazy answer, but I would change the hard coded cell indexes as it could be brittle with the addition, removal or reordering of cells. I'd either recommend the use of classes or `$('[id^=ntposition]')` in the context of the row.

Comment: Thank you Stephen Muecke!  The two totals are showing the "NaN" error, but I'm reviewing it.

Comment: @jle, Add some `console.log()` statements to print out the values of `i`, `nt`, `nh` and `f` to ensure that they are actually numbers. And do you really want `.keyup()`? I suspect it should be `.change()`

Comment: Yes, .change() would also work.  I'll test both experiences.  The console.log() shows i as and int, but nt, nh, and f are "NaN'.  In the model, those fields are of int? type.  Could that be why they read as numbers in the table but can't be converted via Number() in the script?

Comment: You will have to give some examples of the values in those table cells that are returning `NAN`. If the properties are `int?` and have no value, then `Number()` returns `0` so should not be a problem so there is some issue with the actual value in the cell.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to add `.text()` after `cells.eq(1)`. See update. And also see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u1umgnd/1/) for an example

Comment: That did it!  The .text() was the only thing missing.  Thanks very much!  Everyone's expertise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the difference between [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

- `val()` is for getting and setting values for form elements, `input`, `select` etc.
- `text()` is for getting and setting plain unformatted text for non form elements.
- `html()` is for getting and setting inner Html from a node

So what you want is:

```
$tp.text($nh.text() + $i.val() - $nt.text());
$fp.text($nh.text() + $i.val() - $f.text());
```

Also be careful as `+` is both mathematical addition **and** string concatenation in javascript so you may want to cast your parse the strings to the appropriate number type.

Comment: Thank you Jon P - this is a great answer.  I'm fighting with the radix while using parseInt on the text values involved in the addition, but this appears as though it would do the trick.